# How to calculate the size of blocks of values in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list like this:

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

How can I calculate the size of blocks of values of `1` and `0` in this list?
The resulting list will look like :

```
list_2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Please consider providing more details on what the problem is.

Comment: According to the text requirement the result should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `cumsum` with `diff` then `transform` `count`

```
s = pd.Series(list_1)
s.groupby(s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).transform('count')
Out[91]: 
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     4
8     4
9     4
10    1
11    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: can you explain? i want to understand those methods >?

Comment: @adirabargil first do the diff and eq the value return not 0 mean the value change then we do cumsum and the subgroup key created

Answer (score 4):

NumPy way -

```
In [15]: a = np.array(list_1)

In [16]: c = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,a[:-1] != a[1:],True]))

In [17]: np.repeat(c,c)
Out[17]: array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1])
```

Timings on `10,000x` tiled version of given sample :

```
In [45]: list_1
Out[45]: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

In [46]: list_1 = np.tile(list_1,10000).tolist()

# Itertools groupby way :
In [47]: %%timeit
    ...: result = []
    ...: for k, v in groupby(list_1):
    ...:     length = len(list(v))
    ...:     result.extend([length] * length)
28.7 ms ± 435 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Pandas way :
In [48]: %%timeit
    ...: s = pd.Series(list_1)
    ...: s.groupby(s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).transform('count')
28.3 ms ± 324 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# NumPy way :
In [49]: %%timeit
    ...: a = np.array(list_1)
    ...: c = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,a[:-1] != a[1:],True]))
    ...: np.repeat(c,c)
8.16 ms ± 76.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `from itertools import groupby` as `groupby(list_1)` will produce the following structure

```
>> [(k, list(v)) for k, v in groupby(list_1)]
[(0, [0]), (1, [1, 1]), (0, [0, 0, 0]), (1, [1, 1, 1, 1]), (0, [0]), (1, [1])]
```

Then just iterate and add as many boxes as the length of the list

```
result = []
for k, v in groupby(list_1):
    length = len(list(v))
    result.extend([length] * length) # list of value 'length' of size 'length'

print(result)  # [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `shift` and `cumsum`

```
s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just count the occurences of the items with the same value

```
def get_counts():
    counts = []
    previous = -1
    group_index = -1
    for x in list_1:
        if previous == x:
            counts[group_index] += 1
        else:
            group_index += 1
            counts.append(1)
        previous = x 
    return counts
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]

and then

```
list_2 = []
for i in get_counts():
    list_2 += [i] * i
```

[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]